# MYSQL AND operator comparison in same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute this query, could anyone help why is it not working.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (p.fld_tag_id) 
FROM tbl_tag_properties as p 
WHERE 3 = (SELECT count(c.fld_tag_id) 
FROM tbl_tag_properties as c 
WHERE c.fld_tag_category_value_id in (67, 20, 48) 
and c.fld_tag_id = p.fld_tag_id) 
AND p.fld_tag_category_value_id IN (55, 56) 
AND p.fld_tag_category_value_id IN (74, 75)
```

while ....

this query is executing properly with single AND operator in the end, but I need multiple AND operator.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (p.fld_tag_id) 
FROM tbl_tag_properties as p 
WHERE 3 = (SELECT count(c.fld_tag_id) 
FROM tbl_tag_properties as c 
WHERE c.fld_tag_category_value_id in (67, 20, 48) 
and c.fld_tag_id = p.fld_tag_id) 
AND p.fld_tag_category_value_id IN (55, 56)
```

Comment: If the query executed with both of those as 'AND', you would get no results every time unless there's an overlap between the two lists. Absent a SQL solution, you can always just calculate the intersection of the list ahead of time.

Answer (score 4):

How can you restric ID into one range and then try to restrict them again for another range? ;)
It's like I want to colour to be BLACK `and` WHITE. Impossible unless you want the colour to be `in` (BLACK, WHITE). The other way colour = BLACK `or` colour = WHITE.... I just took the example of colour for easy explanation.

try this out for first query:

```
AND p.fld_tag_category_value_id IN (55, 56, 74, 75)
```

You are doing a self join here, but what does that `WHERE 3 =` for? If you could simply tell, what your expect output given your table schema, that would have been much better.

If you want to limit the records returned for 3 then use `LIMIT`. Please take a look at the following sample and let us know what really do need. :) Happy to understand and help you out.

[* SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9cd0c/2)

Comment: We have multiple cases which we check with AND operator...... each case have different Ids..... we can't use all Ids with single AND Operator

Answer (score 2):

Your two `AND` lines are mutually exclusive :

```
AND p.fld_tag_category_value_id IN (55, 56) 
AND p.fld_tag_category_value_id IN (74, 75)
```

Your value can't be in `55, 56` and in `74, 75` at the same time.

Try :

```
SELECT DISTINCT (p.fld_tag_id) 
FROM tbl_tag_properties as p 
WHERE 3 = (SELECT count(c.fld_tag_id) 
FROM tbl_tag_properties as c 
WHERE c.fld_tag_category_value_id in (67, 20, 48) 
AND c.fld_tag_id = p.fld_tag_id) 
AND p.fld_tag_category_value_id IN (55, 56, 74, 75)
```

With OR operators :

```
SELECT DISTINCT (p.fld_tag_id) 
FROM tbl_tag_properties as p 
WHERE 3 = (SELECT count(c.fld_tag_id) 
FROM tbl_tag_properties as c 
WHERE c.fld_tag_category_value_id in (67, 20, 48) 
AND c.fld_tag_id = p.fld_tag_id) 
AND (p.fld_tag_category_value_id IN (55, 56)
    OR p.fld_tag_category_value_id IN (74, 75))
```

That way you can build your query the way you want. Don't forget the parenthesis though.

Comment: We have multiple cases which we check with AND operator...... each case have different Ids..... we can't use all Ids with single AND Operator

Comment: Then you'll have to find another way. This won't work.
I edited my answer with another possibility, but it uses OR operators.

Answer (score 1):

Your last AND should hold all possible values.
To explain why it failed, assume `p.fld_tag_category_value_id = 55`.
Then in your query first AND i.e

```
AND p.fld_tag_category_value_id IN (55, 56) // Will evaluate to TRUE
```

will be true but second AND condition will be FALSE, because a single value cannot satisfy both the AND conditions that you have.

```
AND p.fld_tag_category_value_id IN (74, 75) // Will evaluate to FALSE
```

If you try with following it will work.

```
....
AND p.fld_tag_category_value_id IN (55, 56, 74, 75)
```

Comment: We have multiple cases which we check with AND operator...... each case have different Ids..... we can't use all Ids with single AND Operator

Comment: @user1863272 single value cannot satisfy both AND conditions, you need to change your logic, can you please explain the case in which you are checking.

Comment: We have different Data presentation type each have different IDs to be passed. I can't pass the IDs with single AND operator because the result comes wrong. For each data representation must be AND Operator there.